# Deploy Maven Project to Nexus via Gitlab CICD

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, nexus

So my problem is the following, I have a freshly installed Nexus 3 instance running in a Docker Container inside my Portainer instance. Currently I'm developing a Java Library that I build with Maven. I want to upload my build artifacts via Gitlab CI to Nexus to store and reuse them. In the following you can find my configuration for my Java Project, Gitlab CI Script and what my Nexus looks like.

**Nexus**:
[image: Nexus Setup]

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.kryofex</groupId>
    <artifactId>PluginAPI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <!--<snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>-->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>${env.NEXUS_REPO_URL}central/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>${env.NEXUS_REPO_URL}snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**.m2/settings.xml**:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>${env.NEXUS_REPO_USER}</username>
            <password>${env.NEXUS_REPO_PASS}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>${env.NEXUS_REPO_USER}</username>
            <password>${env.NEXUS_REPO_PASS}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
image: maven

variables:
  SNAPSHOT_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY: ${NEXUS_REPO_URL}/repository/maven-snapshots/
  RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY: ${NEXUS_REPO_URL}/repository/maven-releases/
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"
  MAVEN_CLI_POST_OPTS: "-Dnexus.url=${NEXUS_REPO_URL} -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - package
  - deploy

codebuild:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn install
    - mvn compile

codetest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
    - echo "The code has been tested"

codepackage:
  stage: package
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
    - echo "Packaging the code"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
  only:
    - master

codedeploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn -v
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS source:jar deploy -Dnexus_user=${NEXUS_REPO_USER} -Dnexus_pwd=${NEXUS_REPO_PWD} -DsnapshotDeploymentRepository=$SNAPSHOT_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY -DreleaseDeploymentRepository=$RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY -DskipTests ${MAVEN_CLI_POST_OPTS}
    - echo "installing the package in local repository"
  only:
    - master
```

When I run my pipeline with this configuration everything works fine besides the deployment. In this stage Gitlab throws an Error:

```
[INFO] Uploading to central: http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/de/kryofex/PluginAPI/1.0.0/PluginAPI-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Uploading to central: http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/de/kryofex/PluginAPI/1.0.0/PluginAPI-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-27T14:58:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project PluginAPI: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact de.kryofex:PluginAPI:jar:1.0.0 from/to central (http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/): Transfer failed for http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/de/kryofex/PluginAPI/1.0.0/PluginAPI-1.0.0.jar: Connect to 78.46.71.23:49155 [/78.46.71.23] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project PluginAPI: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact de.kryofex:PluginAPI:jar:1.0.0 from/to central (http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/): Transfer failed for http://78.46.71.23:49155/central/de/kryofex/PluginAPI/1.0.0/PluginAPI-1.0.0.jar
```

What can I do to fix this Error ? I thought maybe is my URL (selfhosted Nexus) to the repository wrong or I missed some Nexus configuration. I have worked with Nexus before at my workplace but I have never configured an Nexus instance so maybe I missed something ?

THank you in advance

Comment: Maven cannot reach maven central. Do you need to provide credentials to pass a firewall?

Comment: Yeah probably, I provide my nexus user credentials via Gitlab Variables

Comment: You may want to use your nexus to cache maven central. Faster builds and you may fix this problem too.

Comment: Sounds good, this is the behaviour I know from my workplace to, how can I enable caching from maven-central ? :)

Comment: Ask the nexus admin. It might have to be enabled

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is the problem ;/ I am the nexus admin of this instance but i am fresh and still learning :O

Comment: Then I would suggest you start learning from the Nexus documentation.

Comment: Note: `<properties>/<maven.compiler.*>14` and `<configuration>/<source>|<target>10` is contradicting. Furthermore, they can be replace by [`<properties>/<maven.compiler.release>`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version#java9).

Comment: There is a network/firewall/proxy error: ` failed: Connection timed out ` ... furthermore the pipeline does not make sense to separate steps like test, deploy, etc. because based on the lifecycle you are repeating a lot of steps... furthermore changing the default `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` does not make sense... follow convention over configuration... There are exactly two different type: `mvn verify` or `mvn deploy` everything else does not makes sense...

Comment: Noticed the "maven-central" line in your Nexus screen shot?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yeah i did notice that and i tried to find an config in the ui to connect to central but couldn't find one yet